# Dynamically 'provide' a service

Tags: typescript, angular, dependency-injection

In my project, I have various services that implement the "Service" interface, so I know that every service has `findAll<T>`, `find`, `create`, (CRUD) etc.. methods

Now I'm writing a component which you can dynamically attach to one of these services, and it would call the `findAll` method and retrieve all entities from the service.

I'm dynamically requiring the service using webpack:

```
  ngOnInit() {
      // Load context for serice API directory:
      let req = require.context('../../../../api', true, /^\.\/.*\.ts$/);
      // Let's load the service (synchronously)
      let service: Service = req('./' + serviceName + 'ApiService.ts')
```

Great! now at this point, `service` contains my service. Now I just need to `provide` it, because these services haven't all been added to the bootstrap process but are just used on demand.

Hence my question; How do I 'provide' a service dynamically from within the component? (After doing that, I'll use `injector.get` to retrieve the service instance. I want to do the equivalent of:

`provide: service` in my component, but obviously, since I'm already in the `ngOnInit()`, it's too late for that..

Edit; It seems that, from: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622 there's no clean solution. I stand to be corrected though.

Comment: Just talking out loud here: Create a service that takes `serviceName`, returns the object. And use that service in the `providers` array of your component and use it?

Comment: It looks like XY problem. Why would a component (controller) define a service? It's not its job.

Comment: @estus I'm not sure if you understood the question. It's never the component's job to define the service - I just need a reference/instance to it. This is a DI issue.

Comment: Would you be able to write your own factory service provider? See useFactory here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#providers

"Use this technique to create a dependency object with a factory function whose inputs are some combination of injected services and local state."

Comment: You want to assign some service to `provide` and make it available for injection on current injector. If this cannot be called 'to define a service', what can be then? A proxy service that references other services is still a service (btw, it isn't evident that `require` gets an injectable and not just a class). The question doesn't explain why this should be done inside a component. Btw, the issue you're referring isn't related to the subject, it is about having an access to injector in services. The question is about a component which has own injector.